# Question mark characters on HTML if I use UTF-8 and weird characters on SQL data if I use ISO-8859-1

Tags: html, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

I'm making a page with latin accents like `á, ã, ç`, and others. This site pulls data from a SQL database. I'm using this on the `<head>`: 
`<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>`
With this header the HTML accented characters are fine, but the SQL data is being displayed as `Ã§Ã£`instead of `ão`, and if I change the `charset` from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8, all the HTML accented characters are displayed by a � (question mark) and the SQL data shows accents just fine.
Is there any way to fix it besides escaping either all the HTML characters or the SQL ones?

PS: I've already tried `mysql_set_charset('utf8');` and `SET NAMES utf8`, neither worked to me.

Comment: And what is the database collation?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, but the collation was UTF-8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you see `�` question marks, your document has not been stored in the correct encoding (should be UTF-8 in your case) or it isn't being served with the correct headers and/or meta tags.

If you want to work with special characters like `è`, your html document should be saved as UTF-8 and served as UTF-8:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Additionally, you have to use UTF-8 for your database connections:

> …("SET NAMES utf8");
>   …("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

And last but not least, you have to use UTF-8 for the database itself.

As you'll notice, you're already on the correct path… you just have to *"use it all"* (as I described above) instead of trying one thing at a time and ignoring the rest. It's the combination that makes it work. Simpler said: if you go "UTF-8", you will have to think "UTF-8" everywhere and stick to it in your html files, your headers, your meta tags, your database connections, and the database(s). Use the same encoding *everywhere* and stick to it, instead of using *"a bit UTF-8 here and a bit ISO-whatever there"*.

Comment: My problem was the HTML document. Since I was using Komodo Edit it wasn't saved as UTF-8. Saved it on notepad and now it works! Thanks for the help. I'll look on Komodo Edit settings to avoid future problems with this.

Comment: @Gus Glad you were able to fix it. Well, then all that's left to do for me is wish you a nice weekend. ;)

Comment: Thank you for being so helpful, and I hope you have a great weekend too!