# Why my text in website convert to The question mark?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-family

My original text : مشاوره و اجرا و کمک به بنگاه‌ها

But what is displayed on the website : مشاوره و اجرا و کمک ��ه بنگاه‌ها

what is the problem?

Comment: can you share your source code?

Comment: Perhaps the first thing to ask is - is StackOverflow showing your original text correctly? I am certainly seeing two different sets of characters. This means that some circumstances show the font correctly (as far as I can tell). Look in your browser's dev tools inspect facility to see exactly what is there in SO compared to what is there in your site (e.g. are different fonts being used?). Also I note that a special HTML character is being used - ampersand zwnj; - does removing that make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

i think this is because of your font, try another font.

Comment: i try it but nothing changed

Comment: then check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17874348/question-mark-characters-on-html-if-i-use-utf-8-and-weird-characters-on-sql-data) out

Answer (score 0):

try to use UTF-16 if you are on UTF-8, in all other cases you should also see how they are used, changing it would be ideal

Answer (score 0):

> I wrote this code and it worked...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

     <html lang="en">
     <head> <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
     </head>
     <body>
     <p>مشاوره و اجرا و کمک به بنگاه‌ها</p> </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: im tried did not work , i think my problem is elsewhere

Answer (score -1):

I wrote this code and it worked...

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head> 
  <meta charset="UTF-8"> <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
  <title>Document</title> 
</head> 
<body>
  <p>مشاوره و اجرا و کمک به بنگاه‌ها</p> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: I put the text inside a p tag

Comment: I wrote this code and it worked...<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>مشاوره و اجرا و کمک به بنگاه‌ها</p>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Please edit your solution in the answer instead of in the comments.

Comment: @SamiElk - check...